# Hibernate Annotation Formula NullPointer Exception or invalid identifier errors

Tags: hql, formula, hibernate-annotations

I was trying to use @Formula in one of my entity classes.
What I need to do is select a boolean from another entity.

I tried to put the property definition but it keeps throwing a NullPointerException when publishing, I did it as follows

```
@JoinColumn(name = "SOIR08_FECHA_CARGA", referencedColumnName = "SOIR15_CODI_FECHA", nullable = true)
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private FechaCarga loadDate;

@JoinColumn(name = "SOIR08_RECEPTOR", referencedColumnName = "SOIR05_CON_DISTRITO_TELEFONICO", nullable = true)
@ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private DistrictPhone receiver;

@Formula("(select io.done from Table io where io.district = receiver and io.loadDate = loadDate)")
private Boolean isDone;
```

Then I tried putting the @Formula annotation in the getter

```
@Formula("(select io.done from Table io where io.district = receiver and io.loadDate = loadDate))")
public Boolean getIsDone() {
    return isDone;
}
```

but when I access the page where the property must be shown I get **ORA-00904: "APROB0_"."ISDONE": invalid identifier**

Any idea,suggestion or workaround will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to use this annotation without getting errors.
What I decided to do was to add a column in the table, and fill it when a insert was made, not the best way but I needed to do it fast and there was nothing on forums that worked for me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write pure `SQL` in the `@Formula` (but not `HQL`).

Comment: I did, I tried _@Formula("select io.SOIR21_DONE from SOIR21_INFRAESTR_OPTIMI io where io.SOIR21_DISTRITO_TELEFONICO = SOIR08_RECEPTOR and io.SOIR21_FECHA_CARGA = SOIR08_FECHA_CARGA")_ but it keeps happening

Comment: @Malincy Montoya Try to rename `Boolean isDone` to `Boolean done`. You should not call variable name starting with "is, set, get etc."

Comment: I did, but I continue getting errors. It was kinda important to solve it quickly so I did a workaround. Thanks